# xhr.responseText isn't converted to object by JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have written this function to make ajax-requests to my server that serves JSON objects in string-format. I want to parse these JSON-objects into Javascript objects using `JSON.parse()`. But when I check the type of the object returned by `JSON.parse()`, it's a string! Here's the function:

```
function getDBMatches(){
    var xhr = createXHR();

    xhr.dropdown = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[0];
    xhr.dropdown.innerHTML = "";
    if(!xhr.dropdown.classList.contains('show')){
        xhr.dropdown.classList.add('show');
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.value == ""){
            return;
        }
        if (xhr.readyState == 4){
            if ((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) || xhr.status == 304){

                var xhrResponse = xhr.responseText;
                alert(xhrResponse); // "[{\"model\": \"workoutcal.liftactivity\", \"pk\": 1, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"benchpress\"}}]"
                alert(typeof xhrResponse); // string

                var dbMatches = JSON.parse(xhrResponse);
                alert(typeof dbMatches); // string! This is what I don't understand.

                for(var i = 0; i < dbMatches.length; i++){
                    var link = document.createElement("a");
                    link.innerHTML = dbMatches[i]["name"];
                    link.onclick = function(){
                        var textbox = link.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
                        textbox.value = link.innerHTML;
                        xhr.dropdown.innerHTML = "";
                    };
                    xhr.dropdown.appendChild(link);
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById("xhrPar").innerHTML = "Request was unsuccessful: "+xhr.status;
            }
        }
    };

    var url = "http://localhost:8000/workoutcal/";
    if (this.name == "lift_string"){
        url += "get_lifts";
    } else if (this.name == "cardio_string"){
        url += "get_cardio";
    }
    url = addURLParam(url, this.name, this.value);

    xhr.open("get", url, false);
    xhr.send(null);

}
```

Why isn't the string parsed into a Javascript object?

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(xhrResponse)`

Comment: `"[{\"model\": \"workoutcal.liftactivity\", \"pk\": 1, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"benchpress\"}}]"`

Comment: It's completely possible that `JSON.parse` returns a string: When you encoded a string as JSON: `console.log(JSON.parse('"foo"'))`.

Comment: @Sandi: That confirms what I just said. You encoded a string as JSON. The outer `"..."` are part of the response send from the server, making it a string in JSON. If it was an array of objects the response would be `[{"model": ... }]`.

Comment: Felix, I don't understand what you mean by your comment. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You basically encoded your data as JSON *twice*. Something like `JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify([]))`.

Comment: For the record, if I JSON.parse the result one more time, I get a proper Javascript object.

Comment: Yes, of course. If you *encode twice* you have to *decode twice*. But the better solution is to not encode twice.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I'll look into how I managed to encode the data twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.parse()` returns literal which can be of type Object, String or other types depending upon the parameter being passed to the parse function. Consider the below expression which will return `val` of type string.

```
var val = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("Hello"));
```